# hyperconfluent geometric function expressed in Laguerre polynomials references

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, special-functions, generating-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

I am searching for references that express the relation between hyperconfluent geometric function of the first kind ${}_1F_1\left(a, b; z\right)$ expressed in Laguerre polynomials

for example a special case exists when parameter $a$ is negative and when $b=2a$, hyperconfluent geometric function ${}_1F_1\left(a, b; z\right)$ can be expressed in Laguerre series and is reduced to Bessel function, something like this:

${}_1F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2}; 1; \alpha\right)=  e^{\frac{-\alpha}{2}} (1 + \alpha) I_0(\frac{\alpha}{2}) + \alpha I_1(\frac{\alpha}{2})$

Comment: [Here](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/27/01/0001/) is a relation between $_1F_1$ and the associated Laguerre polynomial